# How to get video url from iframe?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to get the url of a video (.mp4) from an iframe using python(or rust) (doesn't matter which library). For example, I have:

```
<iframe src="https://spinning.allohalive.com/?kp=1332827&token=b51bdfc8af17dee996d3eae53726df" />
```

I really have no idea how to do this. Help me please! If you need some more information, just ask.

The code that I use to parse iframes from a [website](https://kinokrad.cc):

```
import scrapy

from cimber.models.website import Website


class KinokradSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "kinokrad"
    start_urls = [Website.Kinokrad.value]

    def __init__(self):
        self.pages_count = 1

    def parse(self, response):
        pages_count = self.get_pages_count(response)

        if self.pages_count <= pages_count:
            for film in response.css("div.shorposterbox"):
                film_url = film.css("div.postertitle").css("a").attrib["href"]
                yield scrapy.Request(film_url, callback=self.parse_film)

            next_page = f"{Website.Kinokrad.value}/page/{self.pages_count}"
            if next_page is not None:
                yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)

            self.pages_count += 1

    def parse_film(self, response):
        name = response.css("div.fallsttitle").css("h1::text").get().strip()
        players = []

        for player in  response.css("iframe::attr(src)").extract():
            players.append(player)

        yield {
            "name": name,
            "players": players
        }



    def get_pages_count(self, response) -> int:
        links = response.css("div.navcent").css("a")
        last_link = links[len(links) - 1].attrib["href"]

        return int(last_link.split("/page/")[1].replace("/", "").strip())
```

I've been trying for 2 weeks but finally I'm asking this question on StackOverflow. First I used Bs4, then Selenium, and now scrapy. I have a large code to automatically parse iframes, but I need mp4 url. I've already tried solutions on StackOVerflow, but They don't work, so please don't remove my question.

Comment: Please post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and also read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: please share the website URL as well as yours so far implementation.

Comment: I shared and commented, but Idk why my comment has been deleted.